# Ethereum short address attack not fixed

Tags: web3js, raw-transaction

Articles about short address attack: https://vessenes.com/the-erc20-short-address-attack-explained/ and https://blog.golemproject.net/how-to-find-10m-by-just-reading-blockchain-6ae9d39fcd95. The patch only exists in web3 and node API level? Is it possible for an attacker to bypass that and issue raw transactions to exploit any multi-sig wallet?